# How Do I pass the parent control Tag value to the ParameterConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It seems it is very common to pass a static value to the ConverterParameter like the xaml example below.

Is there way to pass the parent control Tag property to it?

```
<StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}" Tag="abc">
    <RadioButton GroupName="AppTheme" dt:DesignTime.Content="Light"
        Checked="ThemeChanged_CheckedAsync" 
        IsChecked="{x:Bind ElementTheme, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Light, Mode=OneWay}">
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  At least not that I'm aware.   It would require you to bind it and there's no way to bind anything to ConverterParameter. `x:Static` and `StaticResource` are fine ways to pass something to  `ConverterParameter`.  But `Binding` won't work

However what you ***could*** do is also make your converter also support `IMultiValueConverter` and then pass the parent tag in a `MultiBinding`.

I'm probably about to butcher your binding but it's roughly like this.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="AppTheme" dt:DesignTime.Content="Light"
    Checked="ThemeChanged_CheckedAsync" >
    <RadioButton.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Bind ElementTheme}"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
        </MultiBinding>           
    </RadioButton.IsChecked>
</RadioButton>
```